# CW complex adjunction map

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

In topology we defined a quotient topology for glueing in the following way:
Let $(X,O)$ and $(Y,O)$ be topological spaces and $f:A \subseteq X \rightarrow Y$ a continuous map, then we have that $X \cup_f Y = (X \cup Y)/(a \tilde \  f(a))$ is a quotient space. So far so good. Now, we had to deal with CW complexes. I know the definition, but I don't know how this concept is used to build up a CW complex. Let's take the n-sphere. The only thing I know is that this concept of adjunction is used to build CW-structure, but how exactly is that done? Wikipedia says that we have one 0-cell $e_0$ and one n-cell $e_n$. It does not say how exactly these two look like. I guess $e_0$ is just the northpole and $e_n$ the rest. Actually, if I am correct so far, we don't need the concept of adjunction because we could just write down a homeomorphism $\phi : B(0,1) \subset \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow S^{n}\backslash\{(0,...,0,1\} \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}.$ Something like a stereographic projection should do this(although I did not really think about the details), but how would one build up this complex with the use of adjunction maps?

Answer (score 1):

The word *adjunction* you're seeing here just means the gluing construction you've already described.

So to clarify your example: the cells of a CW complex are all $n$-dimensional disks, which may be realized as $[0,1]^n$ or as the homeomorphic $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:|x|\leq 1\}$. So in the case of $S^n$ we have a $0$-cell and an $n$-cell. We must map the boundary $S^{n-1}$ of the $n$-cell to the union of lower-dimensional cells, in this case just the $0$-cell, so that the map is the collapse of $S^{n-1}$ to a point.

Comment: Well, there is one thing is somewhat strange: our cells are isomorphic to the open disc(or ball) and the closure of a cell is isomorphic to the closed disc (you suggest that the cell is isomorphic to the closed disc). Okay, so you map the boundary to the lower-dimensional cells? Why do you do that? How is this map constructed ? I mean sure, in this case there is just one possibility, but in general there may be infinitely many ways. How do we get the n-cell from this mapping? We map a boundary of something that is isomorphic to our cell to the lower-dimensional cells and where is the n-cell?

Comment: I am sorry that I ask all these question, but our professor is currently sick and now we have to go through all this material by our own and I find it really troublesome to understand the idea behind this. I would really appreciate your help. Thanks :-)

Comment: It's no problem. I'd recommend downloading Hatcher's Algebraic Topology, where he discusses CW complexes in great detail and clarity. The map can be constructed in any way whatsoever-a CW complex is just a space constructed by gluing disks to lower-dimensional complexes along the boundary and iterating. The $n$-cell is the image of the disk in the quotient space.